# Sql список и количество

Tags: mysql, doctrine, sql

Как вывести правильно список услуг и количество их отзывов? Используется две таблицы: одна - для услуг, вторая - для отзывов. Делаю вот так, но выводит только те услуги, в которых есть отзывы, а мне нужно вывести все услуги, даже если нет отзывов в таблице. Если нет, то печатать 0.

```
SELECT s.id, s.title, COUNT(r.id) FROM services s, reviews r WHERE s.type_page = 'turism' AND r.id_service = s.id;

CREATE TABLE `reviews` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_service` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'guest' COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`text` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

)

```
CREATE TABLE `services` (
    `id` INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `type_page` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` TEXT NULL,
    `phone` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `address` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `position` INT(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [внешнее соединение](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html), например,

```
FROM services s left join reviews r on r.id_service = s.id
```

Весь запрос:

```
SELECT s.id, s.title, COUNT(*)     
FROM services s left join reviews r on r.id_service = s.id
GROUP BY s.id, s.title
WHERE s.type_page = 'turism';
```

Comment: Да, спасибо именно так нужно. А как теперь такой запрос реализовать в Doctrine? Я делаю вот так, но ошибка на leftjoin. Нигде не могу найти использования IN.

Doctrine_Query::create()
                      ->select('s.*','COUNT(r.id)')
                      ->from('Services s')       ->leftJoin('s.Reviews r')
           ->where('s.type_page = ?','turism')
           ->orderBy('s.id ASC')
                      ->execute()->toArray();